# What is the best way to keep association between 2 specific managed objects from different tables(entities) with Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my app I have 2 entities:

**Project**:
projectId: Int64
title: String?
address: String?
startDate: Date
endDate: Date
...

**User**:
userId: Int64
email: String?
firstName: String?
lastName: String?
phoneNumber: String?

And I need to keep an association between a specific User and a specific Project for a specific time interval, specifically I need to know which Project belongs(is assigned) to which user for which time interval. 
As such I need a 3rd entity named Timetable.

So far I have this:
**Timetable**:
projectId: Int64
userId: Int64
startDate: Date
endDate: Date

Another possible solution would be for the **Timetable** entity to have a to-one relationship with a Project object, and a to-one relation with a User object, containing only the startDate and endDate attributes among other relevant data.
Like so:
**Timetable**:

syncStatus: Int16
createdAt:  Date
startDate:  Date
endDate:  Date
project:  Project (to-one)
user: User (to-one)

but in doing so what do I need to set as the inverse relation for both of these to-one relationships ?(do I need to add also for every Project and every User entity a timetable: Timetable to-one relation and set it as the inverse for the 2 ones from the Timetable entity ? )

I also mention that I am using mySql for my backend server and that I have those userId, projectId downloaded as being the primary keys.

So my question is: what would be a best practice to keep an association between 2 specific table records (managed objects) from different tables (entities) for different properties (time interval in my case )  with core data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Data Model should work for your use case:

[image]

`project` and `user` properties on `Timetable` are both *To One* relationships. `timetableEntries` on both `Project` and `User` are *To Many* relationships.